# Invalid login: 502 Command "AUTH PLAIN XXxxxx" not implemented

Tags: email, nodemailer

Trying to send email from outlook using smtp connection. But getting error as invalid login. Checked the outlook credentials and its working fine. Tried with authMethod as PLAIN.

"
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ 
    host: 'SMTP hostname',
    port: 'xx',
    auth: { user: 'username', pass: 'pass' },
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }
});
  "

Comment: The message seems pretty clear - the SMTP server you are trying to use does not implement AUTH PLAIN. Try using another authentication method such as LOGIN or CRAM-MD5.

Comment: Thanks diciu for ur inputs on this. I haven't given any authMethod here. still its taking as "plain". if i give the authMethod: "LOGIN", then also I am receiving the same error as PLAIN. can u provide any sample to change the authmethod